# Drag and copy imageview to another view or framelayout

Tags: android, xamarin

Trying to create an application where a user drags a view (button/imageView) from a parent layout on top of another layout (probably a framelayout) in a single activity and have it stick to where i dragged it (kind of like a sticker).

The user could repeat this process until the framelayout is filled.

Currently looking at handling onDrag events and on ActionDrop just add a copy of the view being dragged to the new container. Kind of like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) except without the removeView method.

Is there a better way? How would i do it if i wanted to place the view being dragged exactly on the same position ontop of the framelayout.